# Bash script - how to read file line by line while using getopts

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I want to do two things in this script:
1) pass a file name to the script
2) pass options to the script

example 1:
`$./test_script.sh file_name_to_be_read`
pass only file names to script

example 2: 
`$./test_script.sh -a -b file_name_to_be_read`
pass file name and options to script

I am able to get example 1 to work using the following codes:

```
while read -r line ; do
    echo $line
done
```

In example 2, I want to add additional flags like these:

```
while getopts "abc opt; do
    case "$opt" in
    a) a=1
       echo "a is enabled"
       ;;
    b) b=1
       echo "b is enabled"
       ;;
    esac
done
```

but how do I make it so that the file_name to be mandatory and be used with or without options?

Comment: a side note: the lines read by `while read -r line` will have any leading/trailing tabs and spaces removed. To truly read lines of a file verbatim, use `while IFS= read -r line`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getopts` only parses options (arguments starting with `-`); the other arguments are left alone. The parameter `OPTIND` tells you the index of the first argument not yet looked at; typically you discard the options before this.

```
while getopts "ab" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
    a) a=1
       echo "a is enabled"
       ;;
    b) b=1
       echo "b is enabled"
       ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND - 1))

echo "$# arguments remaining"
for arg in "$@"; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

The preceding, if called as `bash tmp.bash -a -b c d e`, produces

```
$ bash tmp.bash -a -b c d e
a is enabled
b is enabled
3 arguments remaining:
c
d
e
```

Comment: I found this explanation of shift ((OPTIND -1)):      shift $((OPTIND-1)) (note OPTIND is upper case) is normally found immediately after a getopts while loop. $OPTIND is the number of options found by getopts.

shift "$((OPTIND-1))"

Comment: `OPTIND` remains `1` if first argument is not starting with `-` .e.g. `bash tmp.bash foo -a -b -c`

Comment: In some sense, `getopts` "finds" the first non-option argument; it's the one that causes `getopts` to have a non-zero exit status, terminating the loop. The resulting `shift 0` leaves the argument list unmodified.